# Flutter I can't read an image with readasbytessync with local file

Tags: flutter, exif

i do not understand why the image directly from image_picker work but not the image load from app directory, i thought it was a rights issue (I have the right to read or record), but the images come from the same folder.
I don't know if I'm clear, but has anyone had the same problem?

Code:

```
print(image);
  final fileBytes = image.readAsBytesSync();
  print(fileBytes);
```

Return of the just taken image:

```
File: '/data/user/0/com.wallis.env_wallis/app_flutter/1.jpg' 

[255, 216, 255, 225, 1, 149, 69, 120, 105, 102, 0, 0, 77, 77, 0, 42, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 10, 1, 59, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 134, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 128, 1, 16, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 156, 1, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 224, 1, 15, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 162, 1, 14, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 135, 105, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 189, 1, 18, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 6, 0, 0, 1, 50, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 169, 136, 37, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 47, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 52, 46, 68, 69, 83, 84, 82, 85, 67, 84, 73, 79, 78, 32, 70, 79, 82, 69, 84, 83, 0, 77, 105, 32, 57, 84, 0, 88, 105, 97, 111, 109, 105, 0, 50, 48, 50, 49, 58, 49, 48, 58, 48, 51, 32, 48, 57, 58, 52, 50, 58, 51, 57, 0, 0, 7, 164, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 136, 39, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 76, 165, 0, 0, 146, 10, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 23, 130, 154, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 31, 146, 9, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 16, 0, 0, 146, 8, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 130, 157, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 39, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18, 162,
```

Return of the image taken in the folder :

```
File: '/data/user/0/com.wallis.env_wallis/app_flutter/485.jpg'
[]
```

Comment: Did you look at [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files#1-find-the-correct-local-path)?

Comment: Yes i use this to save and load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the exifs seem to have trouble being saved after renaming the image several times, when I sent a renamed image it was fine but when I renamed the image again that was the problem.
So I shifted the time when I rename the images to fix the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).